# script to move a folder based on csv but with partial match

Tags: powershell

How do I get my script to perform a job even if the match patter is only partial?

**CSV**
A) Doe_John_A_00-00001
B) Doe_John_B_01-00001
C) Doe_Jane_02-00003

**Folders**
A) Doe_John_A_00-00001
B) Doe_John_01-00001
C) Doe_Jane_C_02-00003

**Script**
I built an interactive script that does 2 things, export the CSV and copy the folder.
Both function sections are nearly identical. The only difference is the last pipe, copy-item and export-csv.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem $clients -Directory
            Import-Csv $csv | Foreach-Object {
                $last,$first = $_.Client -split ', *'
                $first,$middle = $first -split ' '
                if ($_.Case -match '\d{2}(\d{2})\d*(\d{5})') {
                    $date = $matches.1
                    $number = $matches.2
                $folders | where Name -match "^${last}_${first}_(${middle}_)?${date}-${number}$" | 
                    Export-CSV -Path $export -Append
                }
            }
```

**My issue**
What I have so far can scan the csv, match the pattern from the csv against the source directory, then do a job. If the CSV has a middle name, such as Doe John ***A***, then the script can omit the A and still match against the A) folder (Doe_John_A_00-00001).

*However*, if the CSV doesn't have a last name but the folders do, then the pattern fail to match and won't copy, which it should.

- 1. How do I get it to match regardless if CSV or source directory has the middle name ("A", "B", "C)?
- 2. Lastly, I would like for it to output to a csv to list the partial match and full match.
- 3. Copy-item while work doesn't preserve timestamp or permission.

Request 2 isn't that important if request 1 can be done.

Comment: What part is not working? You are missing some info, like what is the format of `$csv.Case` and `$csv.Client`? To me, it looks like your regex already matches regardless of `$middle` existing

Comment: $csv.Case = ABCYYYY123456789 - I am able to narrow it down and extract just the last two YY and 56789.
$csv.Client = Last, First (Middle).
This works fine if the CSV has a middle name and the folder doesn't.  
If the folder has a middle name but the CSV doesn't, then it won't copy even though I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the regex to accept any single character `.` if it exists:

```
$folders | where Name -match "^${last}_${first}_(._)?${date}-${number}$"
```

This would match both `Doe_John_A_34-56789` and `Doe_John_34-56789` for a user with no `$middle` like `"Doe, John "`. If middle can be multiple characters

Also, be aware that first names can and do have spaces `"Smith, Anne Marie A"`, so you may want to adjust how you are getting your original csv if possible to make sure middle inital is better separated

Comment: sometime the middle name is full instead of a single initial. what regex would work for that?

Comment: @firebolt126 you could change the group to `([^_]*_)?` to include an arbitrary number of characters up to the next `_`, if one exists. This would match a folder named `Doe_John_Asdf_34-56789`

Comment: that works! not sure why $middle didn't work. the format is very system unless it had something to do with the split and ' '

Comment: @firebolt126 If it worked, then go ahead and mark this as the answer - thanks! And yeah, your original regex was looking for underscore to be the next character after underscore when $middle was blank